# Cakephp 2.9 passing a variable from Controller to Layouts View

Tags: cakephp

The question  i am asking is very similar and already asked question.But It is working for me.

ViewReportsController.php

```
class ViewReportsController extends AppController {
public function index() {
$count_table = 10;//sample variable that is available in view
$this->set('count_tablen',$count_table);
}
}
```

APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp

```
 pr($count_tablen);
```

Now i am getting the error says- Undefined variable: count_tablen [APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp, line 228]

Comment: which url are you hitting ? That variable is defined for index.ctp only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a variable in your main layout template which is likely used by multiple controller actions. Therefore, the code example you've provided would only work on `/view_reports/index`. If you want to set variables to be used in the layout templates you need to do this in the `beforeRender` callback of `AppController` so that it can be used everywhere:-

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    $count_table = 10;
    $this->set('count_tablen', $count_table);
}
```

If you use multiple layout templates you can check which template will be used in `beforeRender` before setting the variable:-

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    if ($this->layout === 'default') {
        $count_table = 10;
        $this->set('count_tablen', $count_table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I learned something new. And it works perfectly fine